# How to use mongoose timestamps with existing document fields

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an mongoose Schema which has a field `created` to hold the creation time of the document

```js
var Document = new Schema({
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    lastModified: {type: Date},
    title: {type: String, default: '', trim: true}    
    ...
});
```

I would like to use the mongoose `timestamp` feature and get rid of created and lastModified.

```js
var Document = new Schema({    
    title: {type: String, default: '', trim: true}    
    ...
}, {timestamps: true});
```

I need to then obviously copy the created to createdAt and lastModified to updatedAt for all my existing document.

What would be a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fields from the Schema and simply rename the fields.

```js
await Document.updateMany({}, { $rename: { 'created':'createdAt' } }, { strict: false, timestamps: false });
await Document.updateMany({}, { $rename: { 'lastModified' : 'updatedAt' } }, { strict: false, timestamps: false });
```